# Convertir una lista de dos columnas en un DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Dispongo de una lista con dos columnas, con esta estructura:

```
 ....'2011-10-18', '99,610000', '', '2011-10-17', '99,680000', '', '2011-10-14', '99,870000', '', '2011-10-13', '100,000000', '']
```

Para intentar convertirla en un DataFrame ejecuto este código:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(cotiz)
```

El DataFrame creado solamente es de una columna:

```
0     2017-10-30
```

1     177,480000
2     2017-10-27
3     177,460000
4     2017-10-26
5     177,040000
6     2017-10-25

Si hago

```
df = pd.DataFrame(cotiz, columns=['Fecha', 'Valor'])
```

Me da el siguiente error:

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 3032), indices imply (2, 3032)
```

Agradeceré vuestras sugerencias para conseguir obtener un Dataframe con dos columnas, "Fecha" y Valor".

Comment: En realidad tienes una lista simple  con filas que parecen estar separadas por cadenas vacías. ¿estas leyendo esto de un archivo? si es así te recomiendo que muestres las primeras filas porque se podría leer directamente desde Pandas. ¿Las cadenas vacías de donde provienen? hay veces que esto pasa por leer archivos con fin de línea tipo Windows (\r\n). Si tus datos no vienen de un archivo es importante que especifiques como comienza tu lista (si lo hace con una cadena vacía o no) y si siempre existe una cadena vacía entre cada fila. Un saludo.

Comment: Utilizo el módulo  " import urllib", para importar desde internet

Comment: efueyo ¿Te descargas un fichero? Si se trata de una url de acceso público sin identificación considera compartirla. Es posible que se pueda crear el dataframe de forma directa, crear una lista como esa con la dificultad relativa que tiene a la hora de parsearla es perder eficiencia y complicarse sin necesidad.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Significado de: ValueError with shapes or dimensions](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/401368/significado-de-valueerror-with-shapes-or-dimensions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Tienes una lista con valores y según entiendo, quieres crear un `dataframe` con varias columnas utilizando una única lista como referencia.

Al ver tus datos se puede ver un patrón que se repite cada 3 índices, tienes una fecha, un valor y un `string` vacío.

Podrías crear las columnas utilizando ese "patrón"

```
a = ['2011-10-18', '99,610000', '', '2011-10-17', '99,680000', '', '2011-10-14', '99,870000', '', '2011-10-13', '100,000000', '']
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':a[0::3], 'value':a[1::3]})
```

Esto devuelve:

```
    date        value
0   2011-10-18  99,610000
1   2011-10-17  99,680000
2   2011-10-14  99,870000
3   2011-10-13  100,000000
```